# How to change (Mac)Vim's syntax highlighting rules for (La)TeX files?

Tags: emacs, auctex, highlighting, vim

I'm a long-time AUCTeX/Emacs user that switched to Vim/LaTeX-Box recently. I got everything working the way I want and grew pretty fond of Vim, but there's still one unusual thing that bothers me: Vim's syntax highlighting rules for LaTeX seem to be different and more "noisy" than those of AUCTeX/Emacs.

See the attached screenshots.

[image: MacVim+LaTeX-Box+Solarized]
[image: Emacs+AUCTeX+Solarized]

Both show the same place of the same file using Solarized color scheme, but in Vim there's a lot more colors, which I find distracting. Particularly the fact that `$` symbols that open inline math environments are colored differently than the contents of that environmnent makes editing proofs slightly annoying. Is it possible to modify Vim highlighting rules in a relatively easy way?

Comment: You'll have to modify the syntax definition for tex languages in `tex.vim`, which is located in `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax` (on my Mac, `$VIMRUNTIME` resolves to `/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime`).

Comment: thanks @Jubobs, I'll try to make my own `tex.vim` then.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more about Vim than about TeX.

Comment: instead of closing the question -- could moderators move it to stackoverflow?